# all urls with https except 1 in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

Rails config setting using config.force_ssl = true works like a charm and made all urls with https, but is it possible to have 1 specific url not to have https?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

See [Rails Guides: Force HTTPS Protocol](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#force-https-protocol)

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl :except => :index
```

Comment: cool, thanks!, btw , config/routes using  :protocol to a specific router did the trick as well.

Comment: True. Also, make sure any links on your http page to https pages have :protocol => 'https'. For example, link_to("login", login_url(:protocol => 'https'). Otherwise you'll get unnecessary redirects. Conversely, make sure links to your http page have :protocol => 'http'.

Comment: Use path helpers and not *_url helpers and you don't have to worry about unnecessary redirects when not using :protocol